# What is the form of the roots for a cubic equation of only the cubic variable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics

For a quadratic equation $y^2=x+b$ we can say that the solutions for $y$ are
$$y_1=\sqrt{x+b}$$
$$y_2=-\sqrt{x+b}$$
For any cubic equation $y^3=x+b$, what is the form of its roots is going to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nominally…
$$y=\sqrt[3]{x+b}$$
But there is a caveat. There are three solutions; one is as above, over the reals, but the other two are complex. Let $\omega$ satisfy $\omega^3=1$ but $\omega\ne1$ (thus $\omega=-\frac12\pm\frac{\sqrt3}2i$). Then all the solutions for $y$ are
$$\sqrt[3]{x+b},\ \omega\sqrt[3]{x+b},\ \omega^2\sqrt[3]{x+b}$$
where the cube root is taken to be real, as presented above.

Comment: note the primitive root $w^3=1$ it is usually called $j$.

Comment: Thanks so much! Is this the only complex number that presents the behaviour $(a+bi)^2 = a-bi$ ? If so, how is this proven?

Comment: @ArielArévalo $\omega$ and $\omega^2$, yes, they're the only ones. This can be proven by looking at the polar representation.